# WinAPI control that accepts mathematic formula as input

Tags: winapi, user-interface, formula

I need to enter the following formula into edit control:

[image]

The formula was made in MS Word. After trying to copy/paste it into edit control ( single line or multiline) I get `M 0.33  Q10T9.1-9.7`.

<strike>*As I type this I am studying the docs for RichEdit. If this control can solve my problem I will accept solutions including it.*</strike>

I have tried with RichEdit, following [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but had no success.

I get the same result as described above ( numbers are of correct size, but again a lot of the formula is missing ).

I am rephrasing my question:

Which control, if any, can accept the above formula as input and display it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own control.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to host the MS Equation Editor object.  It's an OLE component, same technology that ActiveX controls are based on.

Your application will become the host, also called "site".

Comment: I feared this. Can you provide some links for tutorials or code examples? I will try to do my own search but any help I can get will be appreciated. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: I don't know what development tool you're using.  You can host OLE component strictly using Win32 APIs but most class libraries provide a much easier way.

Comment: I would like to use Win32 and do the job on my own. I use Visual Studio 2013 and C++.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: There's a sample in the Windows SDK (not sure which versions): [SimpCntr: Simple OLE Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231750%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: @andlabs: You don't see much OLE stuff on MSDN?  It's not an OLE Automation (ActiveX) component; there is no component-specific API.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's what I had feared; I did indeed mean a component-specific API. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: The equation editor appears to be a MS Word component

Comment: @user1793036: Yes, it's installed with Office.  Since the OP is trying to cut+paste from Word, it seems he has Office installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Equation Editor (Microsift) or Math Expression Editor Light (OtherControls)
Both of those controls are not WinApi but it possible to use as OLE objects

Comment: I have never done this. Can you share link with simple demonstration, since I haven't found anything on MSDN -> I can not handle searching well ( pardon for my clumsy English, I am not a native English speaker ).

Comment: Which the programming language is preferable for you?

Comment: *Which the programming language is preferable for you?* I use C++ and WinAPI to create GUI. If you can't find any example, any language is better then none...